# Spark job status is running but the time of first step start is almost 20 minutes after

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

My spark job submitted on 19:46 but the first stage started on 19:07 why this much of gap, I am facing this issue for the last 2 days, before 2 days it was working fine.

See the image for reference and please tell the possible reason.

The first step is to read the header (CSV files ) from Hadoop.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: check these images for reference


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEN0M.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbSzr.png

Comment: I go ahead a assume you're running it on YARN. Most likely, it is delayed by resource unavailability in your _root.ingest_ pool, so that AM can't get the containers it requested from the ResourceManager. Check your driver log for container requests.